# Failing to get response from local Grizzly server using jQuery GET request in Brackets IDE preview

Tags: java, jquery, get, grizzly, adobe-brackets

I've created a local HTTP server using Java Grizzly, with the basic structure:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Converter.register(); //local register

    final HttpServer server = startServer();
    System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
            + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
    System.in.read();
    server.shutdown();

}
```

When I run a GET request on a local browser, everything is fine:

[image]

But when I try to do it with jQuery $.get() (using Brackets IDE Live Preview), it fails:

```
  function getRequest(){
    var apiString = buildRequest();
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/concord/webapi/from/dna/chr/10/strand/1/52500001..52567500/to/rna",function(r){
      $('#outputPanel').text(r);
    })
    .fail(function(err){
      // WHY THIS FAILS ?!?!
      console.log(err);
    });

  }
```

I can see in the Console that I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/concord/webapi/from/dna/chr/10/strand/1/52500001..52567500/to/rna. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:61484' is therefore not allowed access.
```

When I call for a remote response (e.g. github api) it works.
I'm looking for any suggestions, thx.

Comment: Have you checked what type of error occurs? `alert("bad api request");` is not really helpful.

Comment: @regent Can you refer me to an helpful doc on how to do it?

Comment: Sure. [jQuery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Well, now you actually can see the problem: _No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:61484' is therefore not allowed access._ There are many articles and answers about this error - one of them will be helpful for you, that's for sure.